# SpecFlow tests does not work in OrchardCMS 1.4

Tags: orchardcms

How to run SpecFlow tests in OrchardCMS 1.4?

Steps:

1. Download OrchardCMS from [here](http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/74491/download/348783).
2. Run UsersFeature.ICanCreateANewUser() test. (WITHOUT BUILDING ALL SOLUTION!)
3. Result in Unit Test Sessions - Session window:

   ```
   ...
   error:   Unable to locate <input> name SiteName in page html:

   <html>
   <head>
       <title>A 'script' named 'jQuery' could not be found.</title>
       <style>
       ...
       </style>
   </head>

   <body bgcolor="white">
           <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>
           <h2> <i>A 'script' named 'jQuery' could not be found.</i> </h2></span>
   ...

       <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

       <br><br>

       <b> Exception Details: </b>System.InvalidOperationException: A 'script' named 'jQuery' could not be found.<br><br>

       <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

       <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
          <tr>
             <td>
                 <code><pre>

   Line 259:                    throw new                InvalidOperationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, &quot;A &#39;{1}&#39; named &#39;{0}&#39; could not be found.&quot;, settings.Name, settings.Type));
   Line 260:                }
   <font color=red>Line 261:                ExpandDependencies(resource, settings,         allResources);
   </font>Line 262:            }
   Line 263:            requiredResources = (from DictionaryEntry entry in allResources</pre></code>

             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>

       <br>

       <b> Source File: </b>         ...OrchardCMS_1.4\src\Orchard\UI\Resources\ResourceManager.cs<b> &nbsp;&nbsp; Line: </b> 261
       <br><br>

       <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

       <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
          <tr>
             <td>
                 <code><pre>

   [InvalidOperationException: A &#39;script&#39; named &#39;jQuery&#39; could not be found.]
   Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceManager.BuildRequiredResources(String resourceType) in F:\coding\zulatm\OrchardCMS_1.4\src\Orchard\UI\Resources\ResourceManager.cs:261
   Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.WriteResources(Object Display, TextWriter Output, String resourceType, Nullable`1 includeLocation, Nullable`1 excludeLocation) in F:\coding\zulatm\OrchardCMS_1.4\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:354
   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , CoreShapes , Object , TextWriter , String , ResourceLocation , Object ) +420
   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid6(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5) +1323
   Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes.HeadScripts(Object Display, TextWriter Output) in F:\coding\zulatm\OrchardCMS_1.4\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\CoreShapes.cs:286


   </body>
   ```

That is shown for every test case in SpecFlow I tried.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, raising this on the orchard discussion forum is likely to be more effective / appropriate: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with a source enlistment rather than downloading the 1.4 release?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hopefully have found solution.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't build all solution. Hence the Jquery module was not built and no JQuery script files there. Stupid mistake!